How to fix Ubuntu crashing on startup boot
[Ubuntu startup booting error][1]
click above to see picture
Does anyone knows how to solve this problem in picture below, Actually when I'm Starting my ubuntu laptop, I'm getting this error, I can't login and access gui but , i can access the terminal view like ubuntu server with ctrl+alt+F2 and then upon entering the user credentials username and password. please help me guys.
I have tried updating the packages
sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade
but nothing is resolved and also went to grafical target did cleanup , dpkg and Fsck commands It's totally suggest by chatgpt , claude and Gemini ai , but nothing seems to be working. please help me guys
Ubuntu 24.04 , Lenovo G50 , 500gb ssd , 8gb ram , 4gb graphics card amd.
I was using Ubuntu normally for one year before 24.04 I was using 23.10, there was no problem.
Last night I tried to install cursor ai and it gets installed somehow. I shutdown my laptop and next morning it's crashing again and again.

Welcome to Askubuntu. Please list your hardware specs like processor, gpu, make and model, etc. and also the version of Ubuntu you're using, if this happened immediately after installation or if this problem just started to happen after working fine. Thanks.

ubuntu -   24.04 , Lenovo G50 , 500gb ssd , 8gb ram , 4gb graphics card amd , And I was using ubuntu Normally for last one year before 24.04 I was using 23.10 , there was no problem, but last night I try to install cursor ai and then it gets installed somehow, then I shutdown my laptop and from next morning it's getting crashed again and again

"last night I try to install cursor ai" Please edit your question to clearly and accurately describe what you tried to install, and exactly how you tried to install it. The exact commands you used would be helpful. A link to any instructions you followed would be even more helpful.

Please edit the question not as comments. I just moved the large comment of specs to the question and edited it to make sense.

Please add the output of inxi -G. Thanks. If you don't have a GUI, then first of all, try booting from an older kernel. If that doesn't work, then try running sudo modprobe amdgpu and if that works without fail, then run sudo systemctl restart display-manager or sudo systemctl restart gdm and if neither of those work, then something like sudo systemctl status display-manager or status for gdm to see if it provides more information for why it's not starting up or not running.

Also, sudo journalctl -b | -i error may provide more info as well.
